# UICollectionView exception in UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes from iOS7

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have done a View in CollectionView with CustomLayout. In iOS6 it worked great but iOS7 it throws an exception like this.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:

> 'layout attributes for supplementary item at index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) changed from CustomSupplementaryAttributes: 0xd1123a0 index path: (NSIndexPath: 0xd112580 {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind: (identifier); frame = (0 0; 1135.66 45); zIndex = -1;  to CustomSupplementaryAttributes: 0xd583c80 index path: (NSIndexPath: 0xd583c70 {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind: (identifier); frame = (0 0; 1135.66 45); zIndex = -1;  without invalidating the layout'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to invalidate the existing layout before updating, see the end of the error message:

> without invalidating the layout'

```
[collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
```

[Apple Documentation for UICollectionViewLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/invalidateLayout)

Comment: Yes I have override that method. But still getting the same. Finally I have fixed the issue. What I have done is whenever changing the collectionview frame I'm doing invalidateLayout for that collectionview.

Comment: Could you upvote this question or mark it as correct if it has helped? As invalidating the layout was the solution and you didn't post any code

Comment: Showing code for how to invalidate the layout would be actually useful instead of just linking to the documentation

Comment: But when should you invalidate the layout?  "before updating" what?  In my case this exception happens when rotating to landscape.

Comment: This answer should clarify "before updating." (*Before updating the contents in the CollectionView? Before the view updates its layout attributes with preferred ones?*)

Answer (score 65):

### iOS 10

At iOS 10, a new feature is introduced, it is `Cell Prefetching`. It will let dynamic position of `SupplementaryView` crash. In order to run in the old behavior, it needs to disable `prefetchingEnabled`. It's `true` by default at iOS 10.

```
// Obj-C
// This function is available in iOS 10. Disable it for dynamic position of `SupplementaryView `.
if ([self.collectionView respondsToSelector:@selector(setPrefetchingEnabled:)]) {
    self.collectionView.prefetchingEnabled = false;
}

// Swift
if #available(iOS 10, *) { 
    // Thanks @maksa
    collectionView.prefetchingEnabled = false 

    // Swift 3 style
    colView.isPrefetchingEnabled = false   
}
```

I hate this problem. I spend 2 days for this problem.
A reference about [Cell Pre-fetch @iOS 10](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/241-uicollectionview-cell-pre-fetching).

---

### iOS 9 and before ...

[@Away Lin is right.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33993022/419348). I solve the same problem by implementing that delegate method.

My `Custom UICollectionViewLayout` will modify the attributes in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`. The section position is dynamic, not static. So, I obtain warnings about the `layout attributes for supplementary item at index path ... changed from ... to ...`. Before the changes, `invalideLayout` related methods should be called.

And, after implementing this delegate method to return `true`, the method `invalidateLayoutWithContext:` will be called when scrolling the `UICollectionViewLayout`. By default, it returns `false`.

```
- (BOOL) shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return YES;
}
```

---

### [From Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:)

> Return Value
>   true if the collection view requires a layout update or false if the
>   layout does not need to change.
>
> Discussion The default implementation of this method returns false.
>   Subclasses can override it and return an appropriate value based on
>   whether changes in the bounds of the collection view require changes
>   to the layout of cells and supplementary views.
>
> If the bounds of the collection view change and this method returns
>   true, the collection view invalidates the layout by calling the
>   invalidateLayoutWithContext: method.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

---

### And more ...

[A nice example project on GitHub, for custom UICollectionViewLayout.](https://github.com/Produkt/PDKTStickySectionHeadersCollectionViewLayout)

Comment: I'd give you all the upvotes out there for the iOS10 thing, it's been bugging me for a week. To try to add some value here's the Swift solution:


`if #available(iOS 10, *) {

   collectionView.prefetchingEnabled = false

 }`

Comment: thank you so much for the ios 10 update.. I was trying since morning and found your answer which helped me to resolve problem in a minute. I have upvoted.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. invalidating items (cells) would throw exception unless you'd disable pre-fetching.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same exception: in iOS 7, you need now to override the inherited `isEqual:` in your UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes subclass as stated in Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem by override the method at the subclase of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBound
```

return YES

Comment: please add some more details to answer!

Comment: not sure why this answer is downvoted. this is exactly what worked for me! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely certain how or why, but this appears to be fixed in iOS 12, supporting both supplementary view resizing and prefetching. The trick for me was to make sure things are happening in the correct order.

Here is a working implementation of a stretchable header view. Notice the implementation of the header resizing happening in `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)`:

```
class StretchyHeaderLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        cache.removeAll()

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }

        let sections = [Int](0..<collectionView.numberOfSections)
        for section in sections {
            let items = [Int](0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section))
            for item in items {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                if let attribute = layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) {
                    cache.append(attribute)
                }
            }
        }

        if let header = layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: StretchyCollectionHeaderKind, at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)) {
            cache.append(header)
        }
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        let visibleAttributes = cache.filter { rect.contains($0.frame) || rect.intersects($0.frame) }

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return visibleAttributes }

        // Find the header and stretch it while scrolling.
        guard let header = visibleAttributes.filter({ $0.representedElementKind == StretchyCollectionHeaderKind }).first else { return visibleAttributes }
        header.frame.origin.y = collectionView.contentOffset.y
        header.frame.size.height = headerHeight.home - collectionView.contentOffset.y
        header.frame.size.width = collectionView.frame.size.width

        return visibleAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath)?.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        guard collectionView != nil else { return attributes }

        attributes.frame.origin.y =  headerHeight.home + attributes.frame.origin.y

        return attributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: StretchyCollectionHeaderKind, with: indexPath)
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return .zero }

            let numberOfSections = collectionView.numberOfSections
            let lastSection = numberOfSections - 1
            let numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: lastSection)
            let lastItem = numberOfItems - 1

            guard let lastCell = layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(item: lastItem, section: lastSection)) else { return .zero }

            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: lastCell.frame.maxY + sectionInset.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.: I'm aware the cache doesn't actually serve any purpose at this point :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, because I had code that depended on the content size of the collection view. My code was accessing the content size via the `collectionView!.contentSize` instead of `collectionViewContentSize`.

The former uses the `collectionView` property of `UICollectionViewLayout`, while the latter uses the custom-implemented layout property. In my code, the first time the layout was asked for attributes, `contentSize` had not been set yet.

Answer (score 0):

Select the CollectionView and Goto Attribute Inspector. Uncheck The **Prefetching Enabled** CheckBox. This is Fixed my Issue. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Zva.png)