# How to make a sticky header on top UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, header, collectionview

Currently I have a header cell in my UICollectionView. When I try to scroll UICollectionView, header cell will scroll together with UICollectionView list.
May I know how to set the header cell stick on top? Please help. Thank you.

My current result:-
[image]

My expected result:-
[image]

Here is my sample code for header cell in my ViewController:-

```
- (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    if (!_collectionView) {
        DCHoverFlowLayout *layout = [DCHoverFlowLayout new];
        _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
        _collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, DCTopNavH, ScreenW, ScreenH - DCTopNavH);

        _collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        _collectionView.delegate = self;
        _collectionView.dataSource = self;

        [_collectionView registerClass:[Product_HeadView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:Product_HeadViewID];

    }
    return _collectionView;
}



- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader){

        Product_HeadView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:Product_HeadViewID forIndexPath:indexPath];
        WEAKSELF

  };
        reusableview = headerView;
        return cell;
    }

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    _lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

}
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > _lastContentOffset){
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, ScreenW, ScreenH - 20);

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }else{
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, DCTopNavH, ScreenW, ScreenH - DCTopNavH);

        self.view.backgroundColor = ThemeBackgroundColor;
    }
}

#pragma mark - <UIScrollViewDelegate>
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //Detect Button Visible
    _backTopButton.hidden = (scrollView.contentOffset.y > ScreenH) ? NO : YES;


    WEAKSELF
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        __strong typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.footprintButton.dc_y = (strongSelf.backTopButton.hidden == YES) ? ScreenH - 60 : ScreenH - 110;
    }];

}
```

**UPDATED:-**

After applied Ted's code, here is the result and apps will crash.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Swift version of [tedd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5142475/tedd)'s answer:

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

Comment: Wow this kind of resolved my issue on iOS 12. iOS 13 was working well already. So random Apple, so random.

Answer (score 2):

In your `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method. Add these line:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Hi Ted, I hit this error when applied your code :- Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout *' with an expression of type 'UICollectionViewLayout *'. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried running it? It's just a warning in my case.

Comment: Hi Ted, please refer to my screenshot on top. Apps will crash after applied

Comment: What's the crash message?

Comment: layout attributes for supplementary item at index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xc0000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) changed from <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fde7f702d30> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind: (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader); frame = (0 12; 414 40); zIndex = 10;  to <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x7fde7f73fef0> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind:(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader); frame = (0 12; 414 40); zIndex = 7;  without invalidating the layout'

Comment: Please try this solution that I've found https://stackoverflow.com/a/37563336/5142475

Comment: Thx Ted. I have solved my problem by remove "return cell". Thanks anyway

Comment: It's my pleasure! Please vote for my answer if it did solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a `UIViewController` instead of a `UICollectionViewController`. Add the view to use as your header to the view controller and then add a collection view below that header view.

This way the header is not part of the collection view and it won't scroll at all.

Comment: Hi rmaddy, currently I use @interface Product_HeadView : UICollectionReusableView in my header cell. You mean change this?